# jquery, php and form validation / redirect

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm using `jquery mobile` and `jquery.validate` to validate a form.

I also have PHP validation that checks the fields if JS is disabled using sessions

The form posts to itself (`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`)

What I'm looking to do, is once the form passes validation, redirect to a success page

The validation works fine using js and php, so thats not my problem

I have the `$_POST` stored in a session variable and I'm using `header("Location: success.php")` to redirect to the success page.

When JS is disabled, this works fine and I can access the POST data that is in the session (checked using `var_dump()`) in success.php, the problem is, when JS is enabled, when redirecting to success.php, nothing seems to be  sent.

I get the following in the HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/apply.php" data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 394px; ">undefined</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the redirect doesn't seem to be working?

Thanks

My php file is as follows

- php check that form has been sent
- store all post variables
- set session variables to post variables and store these in the form input `value=""` fields
- do validation
- if passes validation, redirect with header()
- display html form

Comment: If it is not working with the JS enabled, check that the JS validation is not redirecting the browser prematurely (before PHP has processed the request)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're reloading and posting session variables instead of accessing them on the next page using the $_SESSION superglobal array? Just curious.

Comment: @War10ck I wanted to do all of the client/server-side validation on `apply.php`. So storing the POST and SESSION data on this page means I know the fields have values. I do also have: `$_POST = $_SESSION['post_data']` on `apply.php` and `$_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST` on success.php

Comment: @user789122 You realize though if you store 'post_data' in the $_SESSION variable on apply.php, that you'll be able to access it on success.php as long as the first line of your code is `session_start();`. You don't need to re-post that variable and save it off again unless I'm missing something. Not that it matters, I'd just hate for you to have redundancy if you didn't need it though.

Comment: @War10ck As I mentioned in my question, I can access all of the posted data from `apply.php` in `success.php` when JS is disabled. The problem is, when JS is enabled. In firebug, it sends a POST to apply.php and a GET to success.php. The URL also doesn't change. It remains on domain.com/apply.php

Comment: Ok. So having looked around, it seems that jQuery mobile was the issue. Adding `data-ajax="false"` to my `<form>` seems to have fixed the redirect issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So having looked around, it seems that jQuery mobile was the issue. Adding data-ajax="false" to my  seems to have fixed the redirect issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the headers must be sent before JS / plain text / anything like that launches (the redirect function is a header).

My solution for you is to redirect with Javascript instead with PHP.

Comment: What happens when Javascript is disabled?

Comment: The whole reason why I'm doing server side is if JS is disabled as backup. Doing any redirects in JS is slightly pointless